# Adding style to links, on active

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, menu

I'm trying to style the menu when the links are active.

I've got this code to use, but not sure which ID's etc to use, or how to write the css.
The CSS should maybe be something like this?

```
#XX a.anchorLink.active {
color: #fff;
}
```

The website is here: [WEBSITE](http://pilarcoaching.dk/hiltonkoksal/)

```
<!--Active link, index-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#XX a.anchorLink').addClass('active');
});
</script>

<!--active link, other pages-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a.anchorLink').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#XXX").load($this.attr('href'));
        $('a.anchorLink').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // prevent default link click
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});</script>
```

Comment: If you are writing in CSS, you use your id or class and add a colon then write out what you want. So #XX a.anchorLink:active { color:red; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the current page link being 'active'? The pseudo state :active will not work for this.
With the menu you are using the class 'current-menu-item' is applied to the li of the active link so to style that link you would use something like

```
.current-menu-item a span {color:red;}
```

Comment: yeah.. think it's just my english that's not right! But yep, that's what I mean :-)

Comment: Think it's just the words 'link' and 'active' tend to make people think of pseudo classes first, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Close.  You want the `:active` pseudo-selector:

```
#XX a.anchorLink:active {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Don't i need to add it to the div? or can i just style it in the css?
I need to figure out the div, the name to put in the javascript.
Maybe it's just me not following the news in CSS. I will try just using :active like :hover etc. :-D

Comment: @SabineQuardon, if you're just styling active links, this is all you need. If you need something else, then I have not understood.

Comment: That's what i need, just thought I needed to use the javacsriptpart, cause the :active didn't work before. (Been a long time since i've done it, but thx!)

Comment: What I need is, when I'm on the "buy" page, the "buy" would be fx red or so, so you KNOW you're on that page.

Comment: Oh, right, that's something completely different.  That's the *current page*, not the *active link*!

Comment: Sry, that's my bad. Just tend to translate directly

Answer (score 1):

just use :active for style when you click onto the link item or :hover when the style should appear on mouseover directly in your css-code.